# Could not Installing Git on Mac

Tags: git, macos, github, installation

After I downloaded the Git from their official website into my Mac....I have tried for almost over an hour and watched countless Tutorials, including the [official website](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup), but still have trouble install it and actually to find it in my mac. Also after I followed their instruction, the terminal's reaction in code is also different from the instructions. There is just no where to be found as a file in my mac, though it does shows up on the terminal. Although it shows up on the terminal, I have trouble follow the regular installation processes. Could you please spot the problems?

opening my terminals....set up the user name and email into terminal.....
when I check "git config --list", the code it gives is

```
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
core.legacyheaders=false
core.quotepath=false
core.pager=less
mergetool.keepbackup=true
push.default=simple
color.ui=auto
color.interactive=auto
repack.usedeltabaseoffset=true
alias.s=status
alias.a=!git add . && git status
alias.au=!git add -u . && git status
alias.aa=!git add . && git add -u . && git status
alias.c=commit
alias.cm=commit -m
alias.ca=commit --amend
alias.ac=!git add . && git commit
alias.acm=!git add . && git commit -m
alias.l=log --graph --all --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset'
alias.ll=log --stat --abbrev-commit
alias.lg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%h%Creset -%C(bold green)%d%Creset %s %C(bold green)(%cr)%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
alias.llg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%H %d%Creset%n%s%n%+b%C(bold blue)%an <%ae>%Creset %C(bold green)%cr (%ci)' --abbrev-commit
alias.d=diff
alias.master=checkout master
alias.spull=svn rebase
alias.spush=svn dcommit
alias.alias=!git config --list | grep 'alias\.' | sed 's/alias\.\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1\     => \2/' | sort
include.path=~/.gitcinclude
include.path=.githubconfig
include.path=.gitcredential
diff.exif.textconv=exif
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=
user.email=
```

Comment: wait, you can do `git config --list`? Then it is already installed, try `git --version`

Comment: _"There is just no where to be found as a file in my mac, though it does shows up on the terminal. "_ - what exactly are you expecting to see as a file?

Comment: @BladeMight the version is 2.10.1   but I could not find it on my mac as a software or a file

Comment: @1615903 or do you mean it will just be it? So how am I supposed to use it? I followed the instructions on the official website and several bloggers, but the code from my terminal is just different from theirs. So I guess something is wrong.

Comment: well git should be in `/usr/bin/git` but it is not program that you can delete, it is mac os component.

Comment: @BladeMight right, I get that, but the instruction also told us to do stuff like first time set up, but my terminal's reaction is different from the instruction

Comment: and you also can see where **your** git is by running this `which git`.

Comment: could you take a look at [this instruction](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-update-latest-version-git-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/)?

Comment: @BladeMight i get it it's in /usr/local/bin/git, but it has problem follow instruction in the terminal like creat repository, check settings(it could, but the result is not what it is supposed to be like according to official website), not to mention further tasks like clone

Comment: create repository with `git init` clone with `git clone [url]`, and could you show me your result?

Comment: @BladeMight for the `git init` it response `Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/myusername/.git/` for the `git clone [url]` it respond `fatal: repository '[url]' does not exist`

Comment: your result of `git init` means there already is an initialized git repository in `/Users/myusername/.git` that means you need to delete the .git folder in `/Users/myusername/` to achieve the `Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/myusername/.git/` but you are wrong that you are initializing reposiotry right in your profile(LOL), create a new directory with `mkdir newdir` and then move to it with `cd newdir` and then use `git init`, as for `git clone [url]` you need to pass an url intead of [url] like this `git clone https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git`

Comment: ok....but how to explain the long list of my config list...the official website only has like four lines....my terminal got like over twenty lines....is that normal?

Comment: all the lines that starts with `alias` are shorten git commands, as for example instead of writing `git status` you can write `git s` because you have `alias.s=status` line in config, other ones are works same way.

Comment: so do you mean those are fine, not irregularities in my mac or code?

Comment: `is that normal` - yeah it is this makes some configs(starting with `core`) global so all repositories that will be initialized will have default config values from these, and you don't need to set up them for all repositories manually.

Comment: also for all other configs(and what they affect) take a look [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_variables).

Answer (score 1):

git comes as part of MacOS, so you don't need to 'install' git, just open terminal and type 'git', a prompt window will appear to ask you to install the git tool for the Terminal.

Comment: I tried that as well, but still could not see it as a software or file in my mac or install as the official website instructed